# What does "Blueprint status: Invalid settings" mean when I open SiteEdit in SDL Tridion?

Tags: tridion, siteedit

I've just started SiteEdit enabling my first Tridion project, using SiteEdit 2009 SP2. Whilst it seems to be working OK for most of my components, whenever I open a page in SiteEdit mode the following message always appears at the top:

> Blueprint status: Invalid settings

Does anyone know what is causing this, and how I can prevent it from appearing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this error might be to do with the SiteEdit 2009 TBBs. These attempt to set the Blueprint Context, so that it's possible to edit a parent component on a SiteEdit page without clicking 'Enable parent editing'

The current user may not have the right permissions to check the Blueprint, so SiteEdit needs an Administrator account in order to do this.

This account is set in the SiteEdit.config file (%TRIDION_HOME%\SiteEdit 2009\SiteEdit\Application\Configuration\SiteEdit.config)

The node you are looking for by default looks like this:

```
<AdministrativeUserId>Administrator</AdministrativeUserId>
```

This needs to be reset to an actual admin user, including the domain.

Comment: Thanks Dave - like most Tridion issues, the answer always seems obvious once you know it but that's saved me a couple of hours of digging around.